# Return Value of a pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

I am attempting to make the following call,

```
PID = pthread_create(&t, NULL, schedule_sync(sch,t1), NULL);
```

schedule_sync returns a value, I would like to be able to grab that value, but from what Ive read about pthread_create, you should pass a "void" function. Is it possible to get the return value of schedule_sync, or am I going to have to modify some kind of parameter passed in?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also you should pass one argument for start routine (schedule_sync in your case). see this example http://www.amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html . You can create a struct with those two arguments sch and t1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pthread_create` returns an `<errno.h>` code. It doesn't create a new process so there's no new PID.

To pass a pointer to your function, take its address with `&`.

`pthread_create` takes a function of form `void *func( void * )`.

So assuming `schedule_sync` is the thread function,

```
struct schedule_sync_params {
    foo sch;
    bar t1;
    int result;
    pthread_t thread;
} args = { sch, t1 };

int err = pthread_create( &args.thread, NULL, &schedule_sync, &args );
 .....

schedule_sync_params *params_ptr; // not necessary if you still have the struct
err = pthread_join( args.thread, &params_ptr ); // just pass NULL instead
 .....

void *schedule_sync( void *args_v ) {
   shedule_sync_params *args = args_v;
   ....
   args->result = return_value;
   return args;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, schedule_sync is part of the gridlabd project, I also just noticed that PID was a poor name for that function return, I was really just checking that a PID was created (later in the code). I am aware that the thread is &t and I would have to make another function call to get the actual pid.  I"m still trying to figure out if you can get a "return" value from a function passed.

Comment: So this might be due to my limited knowledge, but if a function is void, can it "return" args? also I think I kind of see where you're going with this, and it looks like it would work if I can massage the code into a form similar, just to be sure I understand the way I read it pthread_join means essentially give priority to the function passed in over the calling thread, (I.E. make sure that one does some work right away instead of the processor taking up all it's time on the "main")

Comment: @onaclov: It's not `void` at all, it returns a `void*` which is convertible to and from any pointer type. `pthead_join` doesn't operate on priorities, it simply waits until the other thread has finished and gives you its return value.

Comment: You do not need to use an explicit "&" to take the address of a function; the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: @Daniel True, but that needed rewriting anyway and explicitness is generally the better style.

Answer (score 3):

In order to catch the return value of child thread in parent(read as main) thread.

**You have to :**

1) Joint the child threads with main thread. So that main thread stays and waits for the child threads to do their stuff and exit.

2) Catch the return value of child thread while exiting. Child thread shall call pthread_exit(&ret_val), where ret_val holds the exit value of the function(child thread was executing)

**Info:**

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **rval_ptr);

void pthread_exit(void *rval_ptr);
```

**Explanation:**

****Main Function:****

After pthread_create, join child thread:

```
pthread_join(thread_id, (void**)&(p_ret_val_of_child_thread));
```

***Child Thread Processing Function:***

```
  ret_val_of_child_thread = 10;

  pthread_exit(&ret_val_of_child_thread);
  } /* Child Thread Function Handler Ends */
```

***Main Function:***
  After Child Thread is done executing, one can catch its return value in main thread from "*(valid typecast *) *p_ret_val_of_child_thread"

**The second argument of pthread_join holds the return value of child thread function handler exit value.**

Comment: tried to format your code (not overly successful ;-) Please edit and improve

Comment: Thanks a lot ! First timer here, was running out of time, couldn't check all the Options at once :-)

Answer (score 1):

schedule_sync should return void* which can be anything. You can grab the value with pthread_join.

```
//Function shoulde be look like this
void* schedule_sync(void* someStructureWithArguments);

//Call pthread_create like so
pthread_create(&t, NULL, schedule_sync, locationOfSomeStructureWithArguments);
```

When thread terminates

```
pthread_joint(&t, locationToPutReturnValue);
```

Don't have a development enviroment, so I can't get you the exact sequence just yet, but this will hopefully get you started.

Comment: Looks like Potatoswatter beat me to it.